# How to open multiple button with same class?

Tags: python, selenium

In the website, I want to scrape there are different dropdown lists. I want to open before copying data.

I have structured the flow like this:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[class = "undefined event__expander event__expander--close"]')
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

But if I run it, I can open only the first list and the others are still closed.
Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure you're looping over all the buttons? Try printing out "button" in the for loop and see what you get? or check the length of buttons list .. print (len(buttons))

Comment: can you share a link to the page you are working on and more your code?

Comment: This is the link of the website https://www.diretta.it/. I have created a loop based on `games = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class = "event__match event__match--live event__match--last event__match--twoLine"]')` to scrap home team name, away team name & actual minute of play for the live events. Until now I receive only data from the visibile sections, not the "hidden" ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.get('https://www.diretta.it/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[class = "undefined event__expander event__expander--close"]')
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

It might have been due to the accept cookies but your code works after you click it.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, yesterday it was working, today it gives mr this error message  `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <svg class="undefined event__expander event__expander--close">...</svg> is not clickable at point (868, 557). Other element would receive the click: <div id="onetrust-group-container" class="ot-sdk-columns ot-sdk-ten">...</div>`

Comment: @Lore. Hey I saw you had a post about sofascore api. undelete the post and I can help you out.

Comment: Undeleted post. Tx